# Using np.gradient with datetimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, datetime

I am trying to use `np.gradient` to take the derivative with respect to time but `np.gradient` throws an error when using datetime objects. I want to use `np.gradient` because it conserves shape but can't figure out how to get around this error.

I can't set a constant dt as in 3 hours since my time data is irregularly spaced and the only other similar question I found did not have a solution.  Below is some example data

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt


y = np.array([10.,12.,11.,15.,16.,20.])
times = np.array([dt.datetime(2019,10,1,12,3),dt.datetime(2019,10,1,12,40),dt.datetime(2019,10,1,14,5),
                  dt.datetime(2019,10,1,18,7),dt.datetime(2019,10,1,22,8),dt.datetime(2019,10,2,1,3)])

np.gradient(y,times)
```

The output should be an array of d(y)/d(times)

Comment: What error does it throw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to convert `times` into a simpler dtype that numpy can work with easier.  One way to do this would be to convert to `datetime64[s]` and then to `int64`.  Once we do that we can call gradient.  The result will be in units per second.

```
time_seconds = times.astype('datetime64[s]').astype('int64')

np.gradient(y, time_seconds)
```

Comment: So then to be clear the units are in `second^{-1}` in your case. Is this the only way to do it, would be nice if numpy handled it itself :(